# Reading CSV files and inserting in a SQL database in VB.Net

Tags: performance, sql, csv, vb.net

This program reads all files in a folder and subfolders line by line, converts them in a supported character set, replaces all unsupported characters and inserts them in a SQL database. My idea was to insert all CSV files.

It works fine indeed but it takes a long time to insert all the data, especially for files that are larger than 100 MB. How could I improve in this code?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class SQL_Data_Form

#Region "Felder"

    Private _table As String = ""

#End Region


    Structure SeekZeilen
        Dim erste_Zeile As String()
        Dim _Rest As String()
    End Structure


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim conn As New DBUmgebung.cdb
        conn.PruefPasswort("ASW@")
    End Sub

    Public Sub ReplaceChars(ByRef _Rest() As String)

        For i As Integer = 0 To _Rest.Length - 1
            _Rest(i) = _Rest(i).Replace("\t", Constants.vbTab).Replace("\n", Constants.vbLf).
                                Replace("\r", Constants.vbCr).Replace("\""", """").Replace("\\", "\")

        Next

    End Sub



    Private Sub btnAusfuehren_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAusführen.Click

        Dim ListPathFiles As List(Of String) = ListFiles.GetFileList(TextBox1.Text, False)

        For Each filePath As String In ListPathFiles 
            Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(filePath)

            _table = fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, String.Empty)

            Try
                View("connect", 15, "")

                Dim conn As New DBUmgebung.cdb
                View("connection successful", 20, "")

                If Not conn.executeCommand("SELECT * FROM " & _table) Then


                    Exit Sub

                End If
                View("table check... ", 25, _table)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                rtbSql.Focus()
                View("connection closed", 100, "")

                Exit Sub
            End Try
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim r As SeekZeilen

            Using reader As New StreamReader(filePath)
                Dim TextFileTable As DataTable = Nothing
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                Me.ParseString(line)

                Dim memStream As New MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(line))

                Using TextFileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(memStream)
                    TextFileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                    TextFileReader.SetDelimiters(";") 
                    r.erste_Zeile = TextFileReader.ReadFields()

                    If TextFileTable Is Nothing Then
                        TextFileTable = New DataTable("TextFileTable")

                        For i = 0 To r.erste_Zeile.Length - 1
                            Dim Column As New DataColumn(r.erste_Zeile(i))

                            Column.ReadOnly = True
                            TextFileTable.Columns.Add(Column)
                        Next
                    End If

                    DataGridView1.DataSource = TextFileTable
                End Using

                While Not reader.EndOfStream
                    line = reader.ReadLine()
                    Me.ParseString(line)
                    memStream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(line))

                    Using TextFileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(memStream)
                        TextFileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                        TextFileReader.SetDelimiters(";") 

                        DataGridView1.DataSource = TextFileTable
                        Try
                                r._Rest = TextFileReader.ReadFields()


                                ReplaceChars(r._Rest)

                                If Not r._Rest Is Nothing Then
                                    Dim oSQL As New DBUmgebung.cdb.SQL()
                                    oSQL.init()
                                    AddParameters(oSQL, r)
                                    oSQL.ausfuehrenSQL(DBUmgebung.cdb.KSQLCommand.INSERT, _table, "")
                                    View("insert: ", 35, String.Join(", ", r._Rest))


                                    Dim dtRow As DataRow = TextFileTable.NewRow

                                    For i = 0 To r._Rest.Length - 1

                                        dtRow(i) = r._Rest(i).ToString()
                                    Next

                                    TextFileTable.Rows.Add(dtRow)
                                    DataGridView1.Refresh()
                                    Application.DoEvents()
                            End If
                        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                            MsgBox("Error! " & ex.Message & _
                            "")

                        Catch sqlEx As SqlException
                            MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.Message)
                            Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error!")
                            rtbSql.Focus()
                            Exit For
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                            rtbSql.Focus()
                            Exit For

                        End Try
                    End Using
                End While
            End Using
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ParseString(ByRef value As String)
        If value.Contains("\"""";") Then
            value = value.Replace("\"""";", "\"""""";")
            value = value.Replace("\""""" & Environment.NewLine, "\""""""" & Environment.NewLine)
        End If

        If value.Contains("\""") Then
            value = value.Replace("\""""", Constants.vbNullChar)
            value = value.Replace("\""", "\""""")
            value = value.Replace(Constants.vbNullChar, "\""""")
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub View(Message As String, value As Integer, pathname As String)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Message & pathname & Environment.NewLine)

        ProgressBar1.Value = value
    End Sub


    Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDoubleClick
        Dim result As DialogResult = FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()

        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        End If

    End Sub



    Private Sub SQL_Data_Form_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(Me, "close the program?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            e.Cancel = False
        Else
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim conn As New DBUmgebung.cdb
        View("connect", 15, _table)

        Try

            View("querying...", 50, "")
            conn.executeCommand(rtbSql.Text)
            View("Query successful", 90, "")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        View("connection closed", 100, "")

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddParameters(ByRef db As DBUmgebung.cdb.SQL, r As SeekZeilen)
        Try
            Dim dummyDate As Date

            For i As Integer = 0 To r.erste_Zeile.Length - 1
                Dim value As String = ZeichensatzAnpassen(r._Rest(i))

                If value = "" Then
                    db.FeldWertChar(r.erste_Zeile(i), DBNull.Value)

                ElseIf value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(value) Then
                    db.FeldWertChar(r.erste_Zeile(i), DBNull.Value)

                ElseIf Date.TryParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dummyDate) Then
                    db.FeldWertDate(r.erste_Zeile(i), value)

                ElseIf IsNumeric(value) Then
                    If value.Contains(",") Then
                        db.FeldWertDecimal(r.erste_Zeile(i), value.Replace(",", "."))
                    Else
                        db.FeldWertInteger(r.erste_Zeile(i), value)
                    End If

                Else
                    db.FeldWertChar(r.erste_Zeile(i), value)

                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ZeichensatzAnpassen(ByVal input As String) As String
        Dim OriginalCodierung As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        Dim iso8859 As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
        Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default

        Dim OriginalBytes As Byte() = OriginalCodierung.GetBytes(input)
        Dim result As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(OriginalCodierung, iso8859, OriginalBytes)
        Dim s As String = enc.GetString(result)
        Return s

    End Function
End Class
Public Class ListFiles
    Public Shared Function GetFileList(ByVal Root As String, Optional ByVal SubFolders As Boolean = True) As List(Of String)
        Dim FileList As New List(Of String)
        SeekFiles(Root, FileList, SubFolders)

        Return FileList
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub SeekFiles(ByVal Root As String, ByRef FileArray As List(Of String), ByVal SubFolders As Boolean)
        Try
            Dim Files() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Root)
            Dim Folders() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Root)

            For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(Files)
                FileArray.Add(Files(i).ToString)

            Next
            If SubFolders = True Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(Folders)
                    SeekFiles(Folders(i), FileArray, SubFolders)

                Next
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! I edited a bit your post to clarify the wording. I hope you receive great answers!

Comment: "it takes a long time to insert all the data" - if the bottleneck is at the database side, consider wrapping all the inserts from a file inside a transaction. Based on the exact database system you are using, it may offer other ways of performing fast bulk-inserts (some can even be provided with the csv file).

Comment: after research i found out that microsoft text driver is the best solution, it reads much faster and it's integrated in all OS since XP `Connection conCSV;                    
            sConnectCSV = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=d:\\mmi\\;Extensions=csv;Persist Security Info=False;";
            conCSV = DriverManager.getConnection(sConnectCSV,"","");
     
            Statement stmt =  conCSV.createStatement(); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you insert the data looks a bit problematic:

1. You seem to be doing a full table scan just to check that the table exists: `If Not conn.executeCommand("SELECT * FROM " & _table) Then Exit Sub`
2. After each line read you refresh the data table in the grid. If you want to display the values in a grid, just display them at the end.
3. I'm not sure want your `ParseString` method does. Both VB.Net and CSV use "" for escaping a quote, not \"
4. There's no need to create a `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` for each line. It can handle the entire file and also takes care of quotes

   ```
   Dim parser as New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(fileName)
   parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
   parser.Delimiters = New String(){";"}

   While Not parser.EndOfData
      Dim valuesFromCurrentLine = parser.ReadFields()
      'process the current line
   End While
   ```
5. Loading a 100 MB file into a Datatable can have a significant memory-footprint. Consider sending the data one line at a time to the server
6. Why do want to convert utf-8 text to 1252?
7. The code for `DBUmgebung.cdb.SQL` is not provided so I can't comment on that.

At places you seem to be reinventing the wheel. You've created a class `ListFiles` for recursively retrieving the files from a folder, but .NET already provides this via [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Some design considerations:

1. Don't mix UI code with the processing logic like that. .NET provides the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. Avoid passing arguments ByRef. String values are immutable so can be just as easily returned. Passing an array ByRef is useless unless you plan to allocate a different array.
3. Use the .NET standard naming conventions for class/method/variable names.

Comment: yes, i need to convert utf8 because i get conversion error of codepage characters, and DBUmgebung.cdb.SQL ist just a Advantage Database driver

Answer (score 1):

I improved the code a little and now the program inserts all lines in one transaction, therefore i use DataTable to save all the lines which are inserted in sql db, but it doesn't really read faster as i expected, is there any better reader than streamreader? for example Microsoft TextFileReaader?
here's the code

```
 Private Sub btnAusfuehren_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAusführen.Click

        Dim ListPathFiles As List(Of String) = ListFiles.GetFileList(TextBox1.Text, False)

        For Each filePath As String In ListPathFiles
            Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(filePath)

            _table = fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, String.Empty)

            Try
                View("connect", 15, "")

                Dim conn As New DBUmgebung.cdb
                View("connection successful", 20, "")

                If Not conn.executeCommand("SELECT * FROM " & _table) Then
                    Exit Sub

                End If
                View("table check... ", 25, _table)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                rtbSql.Focus()
                View("connection closed", 100, "")

                Exit Sub
            End Try
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim r As SeekZeilen

            Using reader As New StreamReader(filePath)
                Dim cdb As New DBUmgebung.cdb()
                Dim dtInserts As DataTable = cdb.GetDataTable("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM " & _table)
                dtInserts.TableName = _table

                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

                While Not reader.EndOfStream
                    line = reader.ReadLine()
                    Me.ParseString(line)

                    Dim memStream As New MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(line))

                    Using TextFileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(memStream)
                        TextFileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                        TextFileReader.SetDelimiters(";") 
                        DataGridView1.DataSource = dtInserts
                        Try
                            r._Rest = TextFileReader.ReadFields()

                            ReplaceChars(r._Rest)

                            If Not r._Rest Is Nothing Then

                                View("insert: ", 35, String.Join(", ", r._Rest))

                                Dim dtRow As DataRow = dtInserts.NewRow

                                For i = 0 To r._Rest.Length - 1

                                    dtRow(i) = r._Rest(i).ToString()
                                Next

                                dtInserts.Rows.Add(dtRow)
                                DataGridView1.Refresh()
                                Application.DoEvents()
                            End If
                        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                            MsgBox("Error! " & ex.Message & _
                            "")

                        Catch sqlEx As SqlException
                            MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.Message)
                            Debug.WriteLine("SQL Error!")
                            rtbSql.Focus()
                            Exit For
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                            rtbSql.Focus()
                            Exit For

                        End Try
                    End Using
                End While

                Dim sql As New DBUmgebung.cdb.SQL()
                sql.ausfuehrenSQLDT(DBUmgebung.cdb.KSQLCommand.INSERT, dtInserts.TableName, String.Empty, dtInserts)

            End Using
        Next
    End Sub
```